# Does a small contraction occur between smooth varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $V, \tilde{V}$ be smooth algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ and $f \colon \tilde{V} \rightarrow V$  a projective (or proper) birational morphism. Assume that the exceptional locus $E \subset \tilde{V}$ has codimension $\ge 2$.

**Question** Is $f$ an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, such an $f$ is an isomorphism.  Consider the pullback map on relative differentials, $f^*:f^*\Omega^1_V \to \Omega^1_{\tilde{V}}$.  This is a map of locally free sheaves of the same rank.  It is an isomorphism if and only if the associated determinant is an isomorphism, i.e., it is everywhere nonzero considered as a section of the associated Hom sheaf.  This Hom sheaf is invertible, so this section is zero on a Cartier divisor.  Your hypotheses imply this Cartier diviser is empty.  Hence $f^*$ is everywhere an isomorphism.

Comment: Also see Sándor's answer to this question.

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31696/best-strategy-for-small-resolutions

Comment: @ Jason Starr, Thank you very much for the answer. I think that this answers my question. 


Comment: @ Karl Schwede, thank you very much for teaching me the related question. 

Comment: I think this is Zariski's "main theorem", factorial or smooth case, as in Shafarevich BAG vol. 1, p.120, or Mumford's red book, SLN 1358, 2nd ed. p.210.

Comment: @ roy smith, thank you very much for the references. 

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Suppose $f$ contracts a curve $C$. Then for any ample divisor $D$, we have $D\cdot C>0$. 
But $D=f^*f_*D$ by your hypotheses on the exceptional locus, and so $D\cdot C=f_*D\cdot f_*C=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: @ John, thank you for the comment. Actually, I'm not assuming that $f$ is extremal. I thought contractions like flopping contractions might cause a problem, but it seems there does not exist such ones between smooth ones.   

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer. I think you can make it work in $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial case as well. 

Comment: @Ottem -- What if the varieties / the morphism are not projective?

Comment: And then you need to invoke something like Zariski's Main Theorem to conclude that a proper birational quasi-finite map between smooth (or normal) varieties is an isomorphism.