# Determining if a morphism is a blowup along a given subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, blow-ups

Let $X,\tilde{X}$ be two smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $\pi:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ be a projective morphism. Let us moreover assume that there exists a smooth closed subvariety $Y\subset X$, such that $\pi$ is isomorphism outside $Y$, and $\pi^{-1}(Y)\rightarrow Y$ is a projective bundle of rank = codim($Y,X$).

I want to show that $\tilde{X}$ is indeed the blowup of $X$ along $Y$. I have seen smoething along this line mentioined in a paper. Of course, there will be a map from $\tilde{X}$ to the blowup by the universal perty of blowups, but I can't show it to be an isomorphism. I know that any projective birational morphism is a blowup along some closed subscheme, but it's not clear from the proof that the closed subscheme is indeed $Y$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The induced morphism $\tilde{X}\to Bl_Y(X)$ is a birational morphism of smooth projective varieties with the same Picard number (equal to the Picard number of $X$ plus one). This implies that it is an isomorphism (the equality of Picard numbers implies that there are no exceptional divisors).

Comment: @OlivierBenoist : Thank you for your prompt response. Could you please explain how you found the picard number of $\tilde{X}$? Also, why does same picard number imply isomorphism? Is there a reference to this?

Comment: The isomorphism statement follows from [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/99591/82179).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn :  In our case, isn't the exceptional subvariety for the map $\tilde{X}\rightarrow Bl_Y(X)$of codimension 1? Could you please explain how you are concluding from the post you have mentioned?

Comment: If the Picard ranks are the same there cannot be a codimension $1$ exceptional locus, because the exceptional divisor would necessary be linearly independent in Néron–Severi.