# Kähler small resolution of 3-dim ADE singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In Tristan Hübschs book on Calabi-Yau manifolds it is stated that 3-dimensional ADE singularities admit a crepant resolution but this resolution does not need to be Kähler.
Are there some results on when one of these singularities admit a small resolution that is Kähler?

Best,
Peter

Answer (score 2):

An analysis of when this type of singularities admits (Kähler) small resolutions is carried out in [this paper](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=dJf0DQArhzkC&lpg=PA61&ots=z0OPkgQCng&dq=katz+small+resolution+gorenstein&pg=PA61&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=katz%2520small%2520resolution%2520gorenstein&f=false) by Sheldon Katz, see also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31571/non-existence-of-small-resolutions-for-the-singularity-y2u2v2w3) and the answer to
[this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105371/crepant-resolution-of-isolated-fourfold-singularity).