# Crepant resolution of isolated fourfold singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities, calabi-yau

I stumbled upon this isolated singularity of a Calabi-Yau fourfold:
\begin{equation}
x_1x_2+x_3x_4+x_5^2=0
\end{equation}
as a hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^5$.

Clearly, I can resolve this by a simple blow-up. This does not seem to be a crepant resolution however.

So my question is:
Is there some simple criterion which allows me to tell if there exists a crepant resolution ?  In case the answer is yes, how would one go about constructing one ?

In the corresponding threefold case there even exists a small resolution. A second question is hence: Are there results on the existence of small resolutions of isolated fourfold singularities ?

Comment: This singularity has a noncommutative crepant resolution.

Comment: @Sasha: Could you please explain your comment or give a reference?

Comment: Dear Sasha, I don't know anything about NCCR's, but this paper of Hailong Dao seems to say that it doesn't, see theorem 1.2(2) unless I am mistaken:  http://www.math.ku.edu/~hdao/Crepant101109

Comment: @Jason: For details see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609240. Shortly, a noncommutative (or categorical) resolution of $X$ is a smooth triangulated category $T$ with an adjoint pair of triangulated functors $\pi^*:D(X) \to T$ and $\pi_*:T \to D(X)$ such that $\pi_*\circ\pi^* = 1$ plus some technical conditions. Such a resolution is weakly crepant if the right adjoint $\pi^!:D(X) \to T$ of $\pi_*$ coincides with $\pi^*$ on perfect complexes.


Comment: @Karl: The definition of Van den Bergh which is used in the paper of Hailong Dao is too restrictive and not quite natural (for my taste). I prefer a definition from http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609240.

Comment: Van den Bergh's definition is designed, I think, to be as close to the commutative one as possible, so for example under some conditions one expects the commutative and non-commutative resolutions to exist at the same time. That's why it is restrictive, because the existence of crepant resolution is restrictive, see Karl's answer.  

Comment: @Hailong: Yes, but I think that the advantage of noncommutative resolutions is in the fact that one can find a noncommutative resolution with nice properties (e.g. crepant) when there is no such commutative resolutions. 

Comment: @Sasha: I agree! I have also been trying to think of less restrictive notions. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That particular singularity only can have a crepant resolution if it has a small resolution.

### Terminal singularities

If a variety has terminal singularities (like yours does), the then every further blow-up also has discrepancies $> 0$.  (In other words, whether or not the variety has terminal singularities can be read off from a single log resolution).  In particular, every discrete valuation has discrepancy $ > 0$.  It follows that:

**Fact:** *If a variety has terminal singularities, then it only has a (commutative) crepant resolution if it has a small resolution*

In your example above, the variety clearly has terminal singularities, which can be read off from the blowup you mentioned.

### Small resolutions

Ok, so now you want to check whether your variety has a small resolution.  The first thing you can do is look at [THIS ANSWER](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31696/best-strategy-for-small-resolutions) by Sándor Kovács.  The upshot is there is only hope for a small resolution if your singularity is not factorial.

After staring at your singularity for 4 minutes, I don't see why its not a UFD (hopefully someone, ie Hailong Dao, can tell us easily -- i have a recollection that higher dimensional isolated hypersurface singularities are factorial).

**EDIT:**  *Olivier Benoist points out in a comment below that this singularity is factorial due to Samuel's conjecture (proven by Grothendieck).*

However, if you see any given singularity that is not factorial, here's what I would try:

Find a Weil divisor that is not Cartier (the existence of such is equivalent to it being *not* factorial).  Blowup the ideal of that Weil divisor.  (Maybe do this more than once).  The reason I suggest this is because:

**Fact:** *The only way to get a small resolution is to blowup ideals whose vanishing locus has codimension one.*

Here's a quick proof, Blowup an ideal $J$ on a (Noetherian!) variety who vanishing locus $W = V(J)$ has codimension $\geq 2$.  The blowup turns that ideal $J$ into a Cartier divisor (it principalizes the ideal).  In particular, there is now a divisor lying over $W$.  Thus this isn't a small resolution.

Of course, blowing up Weil divisors that are not Cartier is how you get the small resolutions in the $xy-uv = 0$ example.

Comment: Locally complete intersection + locally factorial in codimension 3 implies locally factorial : this is Samuel's conjecture proven by Grothendieck (see SGA 2). This shows that this singularity is indeed locally factorial.

Comment: Karl, in the edit you wrote: "not factorial" (-: 

Comment: Karl, thanks a lot for this very helpful and precise answer !

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there is a rather straightforward way to see that this singularity is factorial:

Let $X=\mathrm{Spec}\ k[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5]/(x_1x_2+x_3x_4+x_5^2)$ and let $D=(x_2=0)\subseteq X$ be a principal divisor.  Notice that then $D= \mathrm{Spec}\ k[x_1,x_3,x_4,x_5]/(x_3x_4+x_5^2)$, so it is a cone over a quadric cone. In particular, it is irreducible and reduced and hence one has an exact sequence:
$$
 \mathbb Z\cdot D \to \mathrm{Cl}(X) \to \mathrm{Cl}(X\setminus D)\to 0.
$$

Since $D$ is principal, it is actually zero in $\mathrm{Cl}(X)$, so this says that 
$$
\mathrm{Cl}(X) \simeq \mathrm{Cl}(X\setminus D)
$$

On the other hand, it is easy to see that 
$$
X\setminus D=\mathrm{Spec}\ k[x_1,x_2,x_2^{-1},x_3,x_4,x_5]/(x_1x_2+x_3x_4+x_5^2)\simeq 
\mathrm{Spec}\ k[x_2,x_2^{-1},x_3,x_4,x_5].
$$
Clearly, $k[x_2,x_2^{-1},x_3,x_4,x_5]$ is a UFD, so $\mathrm{Cl}(X) \simeq \mathrm{Cl}(X\setminus D)=0$. Therefore the singularity in question is indeed factorial. Then, as Karl has already pointed out, it follows for instance from [the argument here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31696/best-strategy-for-small-resolutions/45193#45193) that it does not admit a small resolution of singularities and since it is terminal then also all of its resolutions are non-crepant (I guess perhaps the correct word would be "discrepant").

---

In fact, the above argument shows the same statement for any singularity defined by a non-degenerate quadric equation in at least 5 variables.

It may be worth noting that the argument fails for fewer number of variables because $D$ is either not irreducible (in 4 variables) or reduced (in 3 variables). In 2 variables X itself is not irreducible.

---

Finally, let me add that I find it odd to call this a Calabi-Yau 4fold. I know that this terminology is used by others (especially physicists) as well, but I think it is rather misleading. This is at best a log Calabi-Yau.